# CMake: correct way to have differing link flags?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have both C++ and C files in my project.  I have separate and different compile flags settings for each, using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`.  How do I create different linker flags for each?

It would have been nice if something like `CMAKE_CXX_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_C_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` existed, but there is only `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.

Answer (score 1):

There are

```
CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE 
CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE
```

that look like they can solve your problems.

Keep in mind that you are getting into compiler and platform specific stuff, it's up to you to put the right combinations of conditional to select the right set of macros, if you need a multiplatform, multicompiler, project.

- [Build rules](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Build_rules)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in CMake version 3.0.2 at least, there are the following variables, `CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS`, used in `./share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake`.

They were not documented anywhere I had looked, and are not present in the generated files or cache, hence why I didn't find them.  But they appear to do what I need.

Hopefully, CMake will continue to support them, and not remove them suddenly without warning, as is sometimes the case with undocumented features.